# How do you use a sequence of foreignKeys in Slick?

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

The [docs](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.2.0/orm-to-slick.html#relationships) show how to map a foreignKey as an ID.  However it gives no example for multiple foreign keys. It seems people make their own mapping table, eg AuthorBooks, and so Author and Book case classes do not know they are related.

However there is a `foreignKeys` function defined as:

```
final def foreignKeys: Iterable[ForeignKey] = tableConstraints.collect{ case q: ForeignKeyQuery[_, _] => q.fks }.flatten.toIndexedSeq.sortBy(_.name)
```

..but the examples only show use of `foreignKey`.
How would you use it?

```
case class Owner(name:String, dogIDs:Seq[Long])
```

Would it allow you to map this case class, given that dogIDs are foreign keys to some Dog case class?

Comment: You are going to use Sequences in your data model? Because before you think in using those foreign keys, you need to do a custom Type, because Seq[Long] is not supported out of the box by Slick.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do that we must do a DTO and DAO approach ... where the database model has one to many or many to many and when you transform it the DTO contains a sequence of the other object and is manipulated by a handler, for example:

DTO(s)

```
case class City(code: String,
                lat: Double,
                lng: Double,
                countryCode: String,
                translations: Seq[CityI18n])

case class CityI18n(id: Option[Int], lang: String, name: String)
```

DAO(s) and ROW(s):

```
case class CityRow(code: String, lat: Double, lng: Double, countryCode: String)
case class CityI18nRow(id: Int, cityCode: String, lang: String, name: String)
```

Obviously with the implementation of your mapping table and FK(s):

```
class CityI18nTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[CityI18nRow](tag, "cityi18n") {
//...
 def cityCode = column[String]("cityCode", O.Length(TextMaxLength_3))

 def cityCodeFK = foreignKey("city_i18n_city_fk", cityCode, Cities)(_.code, onUpdate = ForeignKeyAction.Cascade, onDelete = ForeignKeyAction.Cascade)
//...
}
```

So in the repo we build it:

```
def find(code: String): Future[Option[City]] = {
    val query = for {
      city <- Cities if city.code === code
      cityI18n <- CityI18ns if city.code === cityI18n.cityCode
    } yield (city, cityI18n)

    def handler(mainTuples: Seq[(CityRow, CityI18nRow)]) = {
      mainTuples.groupBy(_._1).map {
        case (cityRow, tuples) =>
          val cityI18nRows = tuples.map(_._2).distinct
          City(cityRow.code, cityRow.lat, cityRow.lng, cityRow.countryCode, cityI18nRows)
      }.headOption
    }

   db.run(query.result).map(handler)
  }
```